# VMware Workstation encounters "unrecoverable error: (svga) Unexpected signal: 11." What do I do?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

Have been using VMware workstation for a while now. The other day I did however get this message when trying to start my Windows7 VM:

> VMware Workstation unrecoverable error: (svga) Unexpected signal: 11.
>   A log file is available in
>   "/vmware/Windows7x64/vmware.log".
>   You can request support.
>
> To collect data to submit to VMware support, choose "Collect Support
>   Data" from the Help menu. You can also run the "vm-support" script in
>   the Workstation folder directly. We will respond on the basis of your
>   support entitlement.

I noted that .lck-files have been created in my VM folder. When removing these I can start the VM, however this takes me 13 days bak in time, 3 November where a lot of code is missing.

Possible reasons for this is that I have been accessing the VM both locally and remotely, which could have caused concurrency issues and thereby the creation of .lck fies. Sometimes when I try to open the Windows VM I also get this:

> Failed to lock the file Cannot open the disk
>   '/vmware/Windows7x64/Windows7x64-000001.vmdk'
>   or one of the snapshot disks it depends on. Module 'Disk' power on
>   failed. Failed to start the virtual machine.

On another note I have also tred resolving this by updating to the latest version. When I try to do this within the program I do however get:

> There was a problem updating a software component. Try again later and
>   if the problem persists, contact VMware Support or your system
>   administrator

Please help me. I do not want to redo 13 days of work. (No I have no backup of the files unfortunately).

Comment: i'm getting the same error. i've posted the tail of my my `vmware.log` file here: http://pastie.org/10637360

Answer (score 17):

I too faced this issue using vmware 11 for windows 7 machine but when i disabled "accelerate 3D graphic" setting everything worked and never seen this issue.

Comment: How did you disable it?!

Comment: Thanks Gima. This has worked for me too. On VMware Workstation 12.5 with Windows 8. The Unexpected signal here was 7.

Comment: This worked for me on ArchLinux with Workstation 12.5.5

Comment: Worked for me too ... On VMWare 12.5 & Windows 10 Enterprise

Answer (score 9):

Open the `.vmx` file of you virtual machine and change the line `mks.enable3d = "TRUE"` to `mks.enable3d = "FALSE"`.